# Can an existing electrical panel be left in place but rotated 1/4 turn (90 degrees)?

Tags: electrical-panel

[image]Odd as it sounds, the few inches gained by simply rotating an electrical panel in its current location just 1/4 turn during our renovation (so that it faces south instead of west) will allow us to install an additional appliance on the wall where we gain those few inches. Should that be feasible with the existing wiring? Would splicing in a few extra inches on one or more circuits if needed be permissible (we're in Washington, DC)? Any downside to doing this if actually doable?  Many thanks,

AE in DC

Comment: Can you post a photo of the panel in its surroundings?

Comment: Thanks very much! I'll post one ASAP but don't have one handy, sorry to say, and am not living at or near the job site.  FWIW, the panel is at Code height (3-4 ft off the ground) about 6" from the corner of the wall I need to gain the space on facing west into the kitchen area. The wall it's in forms the left side of a closet on the south-facing wall that creates the corner, so there's several open feet of space behind the panel.  Hope that paints enough of a picture.

Comment: If you could draw out a diagram of the situation, that would actually be quite swell as well :)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. My understanding is that any "splice" would need to be contained within an accessible utility box, but perhaps one of our pros could comment,.

Comment: Hi.  Have a sketch to post but unclear from the site how to post a photo of it.  Advice appreciated.

Comment: @AEisgrau -- if you click "edit" in the "share edit ..." series of links bottom left of your post, does the button that looks like a stylized painting work for you?

Comment: Thanks, "TPE."  Photo of my sketch should be viewable now.  Appreciate the help with the site and the question.

Comment: What sort of door will be used on the reworked closet, and what will be off to the opposite side of the electrical panel from the closet in the new configuration?

Comment: Also, do you know what wiring method(s) come into the panel?